# Combining functions + disabling

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, validation, button

i have wrote some validation, it works pretty fine,  but i cant seem to combine all three functions(when call all functions and trying to write if statement or may be i just misunderstood something), that will react on $('button:submit').attr("disabled", true); when all three fields validates, the button will be enabled, when on of the field will be non-validated it will disable button.

**Here is my code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var form = $("#contact-us");
    var name = $("#name");
    var nameInfo = $("#nameInfo");
    var email = $("#email");
    var emailInfo = $("#emailInfo");
    var message = $("#message");
    var messageInfo = $("#messageInfo");

    name.blur(validateName);
    email.blur(validateEmail);
    message.blur(validateMessage);
    name.keyup(validateName);
    email.keyup(validateEmail);
    message.keyup(validateMessage);

    function validateEmail(){
        var a = $("#email").val();
        var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
        if(filter.test(a)){
            emailInfo.removeClass("error2");
            emailInfo.text("");
            return true;
        }
        else{
            emailInfo.addClass("error2");
            emailInfo.text("Wrong email");
            return false;
        }
    }

    function validateName(){
        if(name.val().length < 3) {
            nameInfo.addClass("error");
            nameInfo.text("Wrote more than 3 characters");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            nameInfo.removeClass("error");
            nameInfo.text("");
            return true;
        }
    }

    function validateMessage(){
        if(message.val().length < 10) {
            messageInfo.addClass("error3");
            messageInfo.text("Wrote more than 15 characters");
            return false;
        }
        else {          
            messageInfo.removeClass("error3");
            messageInfo.text("");
            return true;
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: I don't want to deep dive too hard, but perhaps your RegEx is causing the issue?

Comment: "when all three fields validates, the button will be enabled". Where do you enable the button? I don't see it in the code.

Comment: @NicholasHazel a for loop would block things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is:

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
  var emailOk = validateEmail();
  var nameOk = validateName();
  var messageOk = validateMessage();

  if (emailOk && nameOk && messageOk) $("button.submit").addClass("show");
});
```

And then remove your `blur` and `keyup` listeners.

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68zj9/).

Comment: Okey, i marked it, but i'm having only 11 reputation, so i can't to vote your question :(

Comment: I have re-writed your code a bit and yes it's working, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

From my experience , it is totally wrong to use such technique for validation , now suppose someone inspects your page , and remove the `disabled` attribute !!

The best way is to validate upon submit using your own algortihm ( for example chain all validation functions and return false if something wasnt valid , else the chain should return true)

or just feel free validation plugins , like this one:
http://parsleyjs.org/

as simple as:

```
<form id="demo-form" parsley-validate>
    <label for="fullname">Full Name * :</label>
    <input type="text" name="fullname" required />

    <label for="email">Email * :</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" parsley-trigger="change" required />

    <label for="website">Website :</label>
    <input type="text" name="website" parsley-trigger="change" parsley-type="url" />

    <label for="message">Message (20 chars min, 200 max) :</label>
    <textarea name="message" parsley-trigger="keyup" parsley-rangelength="[20,200]"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'm just trying like to learn something from writing my own code, i know that there is a lot of plugins, but anyway, thank you for your answer!